# A classical result of first hitting time of simple random walk 1

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, random-walk, distribution-tails

We define a first hitting time of simple random walk 1D by
$$\tau _z=\min\{n:S_n=z\}.$$
I read a paper which write

> ...a classical result for random walks in $d=1$ with zero mean adn finite variance,namely $\mathbb{P}(\tau_z>n)=O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ for all $z\neq0$ with $\tau_z$ the first hitting time of z...

I already know that
$$\mathbb{P}(\tau_z=n)=\frac{|z|}{n}\mathbb{P}(S_n=z)=\frac{|z|}{n}\frac{1}{2^n}\binom{n}{\frac{n+z}{2}}.$$

So I cumsum the formula above from $n$ to $\infty$ but can't figure it out.

How to get this classical result:
$$\mathbb{P}(\tau_z>n)=O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right).$$

Thanks for answering.